In Python, why does preallocation of a numpy array fail to limit its printed precision?
Here is a minimal example:
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=1000, precision=3)

# First attempt fails to limit the printed precision of x
x = np.array([None])
x[0] = 1/3
print(x)

# Second attempt succeeds
x = [None]
x[0] = 1/3
x = np.array(x)
print(x)

Running this script yields
[0.3333333333333333]
[0.333]

Why does the "First attempt" above fail to limit the printed precision of x while the second attempt succeeds?

it's probably worth pointing out that you should avoid doing x = np.array([None]) to begin with

@juanpa Do you mean just for the trivial example above or more generally?

As in, you should not ever really do that.You almost never want an object dtype array, if youa re using None in a numpy array, you are almost certainly doing something wrong.  If you want to initialize an "empty" array, use np.zeros or np.empty with whatever dtype you need (and it's good practice to specify a dtype when using np.array()as well!)

@juanpa +1 Very good points! Thanks.

When running:
x = np.array([None])
x[0] = 1/3
print(x)

x is an object array (that contains python floats), not an array with a float dtype like your second attempt:
array([0.3333333333333333], dtype=object)

This ignores the print options.
You can reproduce this simply with:
print(np.array([1/3], dtype=object), np.array([1/3]))

Output: [0.3333333333333333] [0.333]
As a workaround, convert your array to float:
print(x.astype(np.float64))
# [0.333]

